# Button function is not working in React Hooks using external components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, react-hooks

I have the next code, where I import **NextButton** and **GroupButton** from TitleHeader,
those components are simple buttons

After that, I declared a simple array **ButtonsArray**  and filled it with those components in the **useEffect** segment, in adition, I 'bind' the Button function to the button component.
Example :

```
 <NextButton function={ShowSearchBar}/>
```

Then, my other component **TitleHeader**  receives the array and render the components inside it using a map function

My issue is, if I use the const array **ButtonsArray** with the components loaded as props in TitleHeader,  when press the NextButton in the UI to confirm everything is working something weird happens

The only job of NextButton  is execute  ShowSearchBar function whose have to switch a const from true to false and vice versa but it doest not work,

If i debug the program, when I press the button, the program enters to the ShowSearchBar function but *ALWAYS*  ***allowFind*** is **false**

Note: if I declare the array directly in the **TitleHeader**  params everything works fine

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { TitleHeader, NextButton, GroupButton } from "../Common/TitleHeader";

export const ACATG001 = () => {
  const [allowFind, setAllowFind] = useState(false);
  const [allowGroup, setAllowGroup] = useState(false);
  const [ButtonsArray, setButtonsArray] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setButtonsArray([
      <NextButton function={ShowSearchBar} />,
      <GroupButton function={ShowGroupBar} />,
    ]);
  }, []);

  function ShowSearchBar() {
    setAllowFind(!allowFind);
  }

  return (
    <GeneralContainer>
      //doesnt work (using a const type array and filled in UseEffect)
      <TitleHeader
        Title={t("TTER001")}
        BarSize="300px"
        Embedded={false}
        ButtonsArray={ButtonsArray}
      />
      //Works declaring the array and the items inline
      <TitleHeader
        Title={t("TTER001")}
        BarSize="300px"
        Embedded={false}
        ButtonsArray={[
          <NextButton function={ShowSearchBar} />,
          <GroupButton function={ShowGroupBar} />,
        ]}
      />
    </GeneralContainer>
  );
};
```

Second JS TitleHeader

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";

export class TitleHeader extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  render() {
    let TitleDesing;

    TitleDesing = (
      <div className="Buttons-Group">
        {this.props.ButtonsArray.map((component, index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>{component}</React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
    );

    return TitleDesing;
  }
}

export const NextButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <Button
      id="nextButton"
      label="test"
      tooltip="Next"
      className="p-button-rounded p-button-text"
      onClick={props.function}
    >
      <CgChevronRight size="20PX" color=" #d6f1fa" />{" "}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Was your useEffect revoked when you pressed NextButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the update you do to a state depends only on its current value, always use the function callback version of the dispatcher, this will guarantee you don't use a stale value

```
function ShowSearchBar() {
    setAllowFind((previousAllowFind) => !previousAllowFind)
}
```